# Adding a Wireless Router to An Exisiting Wireless Router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

There is an existing Linksys wireless router running in the house I'm living at.  Apparently, nobody knows the password nor the wireless key; someone else set it up for them a long time ago.

I don't want to go through the hassle of restoring the thing to factory settings, configuring it, then going around to the housemate's wireless devices and setting the new key.

Can I simply plug my own wireless router (which I already have) into one of the wired ports on their wireless router - and get it to work without changing any settings on the first router?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do this, in order to do this you will need to make sure you do the following:

- Turn DHCP off on the extended router
- If the main router's ip address is: 192.168.1.1 then you will need to set your extended router's ip address to 192.168.1.2
- Reserve the 192.168.1.2 IP Address in the main router
  (Since you don't have access to the router make sure there aren't any connected devices so the router can just take the .2 address)
- Set the gateway address and DNS Address in the extended router to 192.168.1.1
- Make sure you set an SSID other than the SSID of the main router.